# How do i import variable and type from the same file in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, import, interface

so i'm exporting some interfaces and an enum here in my implementation file.

```
// types/user.ts
export enum LoginStatus {
  Initial = 0,
  Authorized = 1,
  NotAuthorized = 2,
}

export interface UserState {
  name: string;
  loginStatus: LoginStatus;
};

export interface LoginForm {
  email_address: string;
  password: string;
}
```

Then i export and reimport in an index file

```
// /types/index.ts
export type {
  UserState,
  LoginForm
} from './user';

export {
  LoginStatus
} from './user';
```

And then i want to import all of them from another file like this:

```
// This won't work
import type { LoginForm } from '../../types';
import { LoginStatus } from '../../types';
```

So i currently have to do this but i don't like this since `LoginForm` is an interface so i'd like to use `import type` for it.

```
// This works
import { LoginForm, LoginStatus } from '../../types';
```

Is there a way for me to achieve separated import for type(interface) and variable(enum)?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to export a `type` instead of an `interface`.

Comment: That's actually what i'm doing right now but forgot to include in the question. I've edited the question.

Comment: But why don't you use types in the `user.ts` as well? And directly import from there

Answer (score -1):

So after playing around it seems that there was nothing wrong with importing types and variables from the same file in two lines. It was just my eslint screaming so i simply turn that rule off for the line.

I can see why eslint is saying it's an error since it's a bad practice to have 2 lines of import from the same file but for now this is the only way i can resolve this.

```
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-duplicates
```